# Proper Use of the Word "Correction" in a Title

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I am employing the word, correction, in the title of a section of writing—but I'm concerned about its proper use.

Here are a few examples of the title:

- Formal Correction to Smith's Conclusion
- Formal Correction of Smith's Conclusion
- Formal Correction for Smith's Conclusion

My writing aims to correct the invalid conclusions that another author drew, thus I need the title to embody that.

Comment: I think in such a context, ***correction*** sounds a bit weird, even *amateurish*. You might do better to call it a ***critique*** (or ***refutation*** if you want the title to announce in advance that you disagree with Smith's conclusion).

Comment: They do not mean the same, use the preposition as appropriate after understanding and deciding on the context. No one of the alternatives is better or worse than the other.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you want the second one:

- *Correction to*: a document after proof-reading
- *Correction of*: an error
- *Correction for*: ... no.

Comment: Essentially an opinion.

Comment: Why "Correction for... no?"

Comment: @Kris (1) Aren't opinions relevant in a discussion of language usage? Or perhaps you think there's only one correct usage.

Comment: @Kris (2) Why `Correction for... no`? - bearing in mind your other comment (above) I take it this question is rhetorical; since you disagree, perhaps you could provide an example in the context of the OP's question. The OP `aims to correct the invalid conclusions that another author drew`. I can't see that `for` producing that effect.

Comment: I agree with this answer. The only use I can think of for _correction for_ would be to describe the reason for making the correction, e.g. _correction for publishing_. But even that sounds awkward.